# Pass data from AppDelegate to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I know this question has been asked a lot but I can't find a similar to my situation. I use `Google Maps SDK` and I want pass my current location coordinates from app delegate to my `ViewController`. I know how to pass it with
 `let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate` but I want to change my location every time my view loads. So I need my current location ONLY on start.

**AppDelegate:**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var currentLocation:CLLocation?
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("KEY")
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("KEY")
        setupLocationManager()

        return true
    }

    func setupLocationManager(){
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

        }

    // Below method will provide you current location.
     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if currentLocation == nil {
            currentLocation = locations.last
            locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            let locationValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

            print(locationValue)//THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO PASS

            locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print("Error")
        }


}
```

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController,  GMSMapViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    var location : CLLocationCoordinate2D?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(location)
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it that way you *can* get your location from `AppDelegate` every time the view load in your `MapViewController` like so:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class MapViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

    var location : CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        self.location = appDelegate.currentLocation
        print(location)
    }
}
```

I'd argue that AppDelegate really isn't the right place to have this `CLLocationManager` logic, though.  If this is the only `UIViewController` using the location you might just consider implementing that logic inside `MapViewController` instead.  If it is shared by many screens perhaps you should create a `LocationManager` class that you implement as a singleton so that all of your `UIViewController` subclasses have access to the up-to-date location data.

Comment: The thing is that I want to get current location only once.On startup.I don't want to get it every time I go on my view controller from a second screen

Answer (score 0):

You could extend CLLocationManagerDelegate on your MapViewController instead, that way you have access to any variable from your view controller

Create new file: MapViewCLLocationExtension.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    ...

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        if currentLocation == nil {
            currentLocation = locations.last
            locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
            let locationValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

            //print(locationValue)//THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO PASS
            location = locationValue
            locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
            //You should call a method here for any further thing you need to 
            //do with location. DO NOT USE location on viewDidLoad
            useLocation()
        }
    }
```

I must warn you tho, you can't print the location on viewDidLoad(), b/c it won't be there yet, you need to move any logic to a method and call it at the point where you are sure its gonna be there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The think is that I want the current location only on start. without updates. e then move the marker to new location. I don't want every time I go to the map to show my current position. only on startUp .I don't know if that make sense

Comment: it wont update again once you got the first since you are calling stopUpdatingLocation(), you already took care of the updates, the only thing missing was passing the location to your view controller wich can be done extending your CLLocationManager to your view controller.

Comment: What do you mean extending.Sorry for the silly questions.

Comment: i am bad at explaining things but here you go: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Once you understand what an extension does, the trick is extending your viewController to implement the locationManager function that is called on a location update, that means you are "listening" to locations update from your viewController instead of listening to them on the delegate

Comment: Actually I know what extension is :P I thought you meant something else . Anyway thank you for you help